# Runtime 3001 error "arguments are of the wrong type are out of acceptable range or are in conflict with one another vba"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to update table row with inputs from userform. below listed is the code i am trying to execute but its failing with msg "arguments are of the wrong type are out of acceptable range or are in conflict with one another vba" I checked the data type and all. If i use .execute method, its working but not like this.

I have similar code where i am fetching the row and updating back in same manner. only one field is updated in it though but its working fine.

What could be the reason gurus??

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pass true *Date* values to your date fields:

```
rst.Fields("MATURITY_DATE").Value = DateValue(Maturitydate.Value)
' …
rst.Fields("LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP").Value = Now()
```

Comment: But its failing after the Select statement when i m executing rst.open. Not even going in to the If Not EOF block.

Comment: Try entering the values manually and/or leave out as many fields as possible.

Comment: Tried with Query "QuerySql = "SELECT * FROM Master_Intrpay_CHK_J where CUSTOMER_ID = 2723" still same !!

Comment: Then, if the ID is _text_, try with: `"SELECT * FROM Master_Intrpay_CHK_J where CUSTOMER_ID = '2723'"`.

Comment: Nope its Number a field.

Comment: Then you have a misspelled table or field name.

Comment: Checked that too.... I am telling you. Everything is same i have just changed the way how i am updating the record. But its not even going there and failing right where i am trying to open the select query

Comment: Well, if so, your simple SQL cannot fail, so something else is going on.